# Can I do something when someone has something in his inventory Java Minecraft Moding For Forge 1.18.1

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Hello I am doing a mod in forge 1.18.1Minecraft I created a new class for my item ,I need help because I am trying to Clear fall Damage When someone has an item in his hand!.I searched on google but i didn't find something!

```
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.level.Level;

public class NoFallDamageIItem extends Item {
    public NoFallDamageIItem(Properties pProperties) {
        super(pProperties);
    }
```

} `

Comment: Please post the output of the program as text, not as an image, unless you have a specific reason to do so. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Your variable i is local and not going to help to know the total records. You could declare it as `global` variable, increment for every taxpayer record you print to output stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should work in your case:

```
int i = taxPayers.taxPayers.size();
```

Comment: Where would I place this code?

Comment: After this line:  sourceFile >> taxPayers;

Comment: I got a type error.

Comment: int i = taxPayers.taxPayers.size(); Sorry for my mistake. You should avoid naming things the same way. It gets confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to split your `if` statement:

```
unsigned int line_count = 0U;
if (std::getline(is, line))
{
    ++line_count;
    if (not line.empty())
    {
```

Every time you read a text line into the string variable, increment a counter.

Comment: How would I get this line_count to output in my check function?

Comment: Instead of declaring it locally, make it a member variable.

Comment: im new to c++, I don't know what a member variable is?

Comment: Usually when I don't know something, I look it up in my C++ reference.  See your chapters about classes.

Answer (score 0):

I started investigating why it displays zero as count-of-records. I've found that this line prints the count:

```
cout << "Count of Records  : " << i << endl;
```

So, you print out the value of the variable `i`. I found only one point where the variable `i` is mentioned, some lines above:

```
int i = 0;
```

It's a proper initialization. But there's no more reference to `i`. So, the problem is: your program actually doesn't count the lines.

I would say, you forgot it, but as you haven't figured out it yourself, I have to say, this exercise is too hard for you. You may try to understand the concept of variables etc., read some tutorials, or watch videos in the topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    string filename;   // Name of the file
    cout<<"Enter filename:";
    cin>>filename;
 
    string line;   // To read each line from code
    int count=0;    // Variable to keep count of each line
    
    ifstream mFile (filename);   
    
    if(mFile.is_open()) 
    {
        while(mFile.peek()!=EOF)
        {
            getline(mFile, line);
            count++;
        }
        mFile.close();
        cout<<"Number of lines in the file are: "<<count<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Couldn't open the file\n";
 
    return 0;
}
```

Code taken from [java2blog.com](https://java2blog.com/cpp-count-lines-in-file/#:%7E:text=#include%3Ciostream%3E,%7D)